# Why don't these variables output their values properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working in Python 3.5 and I'm having an issue with the variables in my dictionary. I have numbers 1-29 as keys, with letters as their pairs and for some reason none of the double digit numbers register as one number. For example, 11 would come out as 1 and 1 (F and F) instead of 11(I) or 13 as one and 3 (F and TH) instead of 13(EO). Is there a way to fix this so that I can get the values of the double digit numbers?

my code is here:

```
Dict = {'1':'F ', '2':'U ', '3':'TH ', '4':'O ', '5':'R ', '6':'CoK ', '7':'G ', '8':'W ', '9':'H ',
        '10':'N ', '11':'I ', '12':'J ', '13':'EO ', '14':'P ', '15':'X ', '16':'SoZ ', '17':'T ',
        '18':'B ', '19':'E ', '20':'M ', '21':'L ', '22':'NGING ',
        '23':'OE ' , '24':'D ', '25':'A ', '26':'AE ', '27':'Y ', '28':'IAoIO ', '29':'EA '}

textIn = ' '

#I'm also not sure why this doesn't work to quit out
while textIn != 'Q':
    textIn = input('Type in a sentence ("Q" to quit)\n>')
    textOut = ''
    for i in textIn:
        if i in Dict:
            textOut += Dict[i]
        else:
            print("Not here")
    print(textOut)
```

Comment: The `for` loop loops over _every single character_ in the input string.

Comment: There is no way to detect that you've meant '11' and not '1' and '1'. You might want to change your "alphabet". And you're iterating over single characters in whole string.

Comment: Can you give an example of the form of input that you're expecting from the user?

Comment: How is this question unclear or too broad? He explains it *very clearly and in depth* above his code: I have numbers 1-29 as keys, with letters as their pairs and for some reason none of the double digit numbers register as one number. `"For example, 11 would come out as 1 and 1 (F and F) instead of 11(I) or 13 as one and 3 (F and TH) instead of 13(EO). Is there a way to fix this so that I can get the values of the double digit numbers?"`

Comment: I'm looking to put in any number from my dictionary 1, 2, 3 etc. and then get the corresponding letter or letters after it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for i in textIn:` will loop over the individual characters in your input. So if you write `11`, it will actually be a string `'11'`, and `for i in '11'` will go over the `'1'`'s separately:

```
>>> text = input()
13
>>> text
'13'  # See, it's a string with the single-quote marks around it!
>>> for i in text:
...     print(i)
...
1
3
>>> # As you see, it printed them separately.
```

You don't need the `for` loop at all, you can just use:

```
if textIn in Dict:
    textOut += Dict[textIn]
```

Since your dict has the key `'11'`, and your `textIn` is equal to `'11'`.

There is an other major issue in your code too; the `textOut` variable gets overwritten on *every* loop, so you lose everything you've done. You want to create it outside of the `while` loop:

```
textOut = '' 
while textIn != 'Q':
    textIn = input('Type in a sentence ("Q" to quit)\n>')
    if textIn in Dict:
        textOut += Dict[textIn]
    else:
        print("Not here")

print(textOut)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much more sense than what I was doing. Though I do have one more question. is the code supposed to look like this then?                                                                                               textIn = ' '
textOut = ' '

while textIn != 'Q':
    textIn = input('Type in a sentence ("Q" to quit)\n>')

    if textIn in Dict:
        textOut += Dict[textIn]
    else:
        print("Not here")

print(textOut)

I ask because it's not working to give me a value for my input.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? @KnittedCupcake My code seems to work fine for me.